# Lint rule for unused function parameters

Tags: flutter, dart, lint

In my Flutter project I found the following code:

```
ExpansionTile(
        onExpansionChanged: (bool value) {
          parent..setState(() => parent.chosenFolder = _entryPath)
                .._pickSong();
        },
...
```

I noticed the `value` parameter is not used inside and could be removed and replaced by obvious `_`. Is there any Flutter/Dart/lints package (former pedantic package) rule I could use to retrieve all such cases in my code?

Comment: Looks like this rule doesn't exists in Dart Linter. You can create an issue for Linter [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/linter/issues) or track similar issue [Add unused_argument lint](https://github.com/dart-lang/linter/issues/2204).